# Rebar3 and Erlang -heart flag

Tags: bash, erlang, pid, rebar3, erlang-heart

I start my release with a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ERL_FLAGS=" -args_file config/vm.args -config config/sys.config" rebar3 shell
```

I have a -heart command in my vm.args file because I want the node to boot automatically after it crashes, using the script.
For manual node crash, I use the command "kill -SEGV pid", and kill the heart_beat_kill_pid.
after that, I got a message :

```
segmentation fault (core dumped) ERL_FLAGS=" -args_file config/vm.args -config config/sys.config" rebar3 shell
heart: Erlang has closed.
heart: Would reboot. Terminating.
```

and nothing happens.

I think that I don't understand enough about the -heart flag.
What do I need to do to deal with the problem of the crashed node?

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation in https://erlang.org/doc/man/heart.html, `HEART_COMMAND` environment variable needs to set for the node to restart automatically after crash.

Also, as you seem to be using `rebar3`, I would recommend setting `{extended_start_script, true}` in `rebar.config` (`relx` properties). This would generate a nice start script that can be used to start the erlang node as a daemon process.

Comment: I did set HEART_COMMAND = ./script.sh , the results were as above(segmentation fault).
The command: 
```ERL_FLAGS=" -args_file config/vm.args -config config/sys.config" rebar3 shell
Extended_start_script is true, where is the script located?

Comment: I cannot edit the previous message, this is an edit:
I did set HEART_COMMAND = ./script.sh , the results were as above(segmentation fault).
The command: 
```
ERL_FLAGS=" -args_file config/vm.args -config config/sys.config" rebar3 shell
```
start the node, I think for HEART_COMMAND I need erlang commands, that's true? if yes, that's my problem.
Extended_start_script is true, where is the script located?

Comment: the startup script is generated when you build a release `rebar3 release`. It will be in `_build/default/rel/<app_name>/bin/` directory.